# Need help forming queryset with multiple aggregates

Tags: django, django-models

I have the following model defined:

```
class TestCaseResult(models.Model):
    run_result = models.ForeignKey(
        RunResult,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    duration = models.DurationField(default=datetime.timedelta)
    result = models.CharField(
        max_length=1,
        choices=(('f', 'failure'), ('s', 'skipped'), ('p', 'passed'), ('e', 'error')),
    )
```

I'm trying to get, in a single query, the count of each kind of result for a given run_result, along with the sum of the durations for the test cases with that result.

This gives me the count of each type of result, but I can't figure out how to get the sum of the durations included.

```
qs = TestCaseResult.objects.filter(run_result=run_result).values('result').annotate(result_count=Count('result'))
```

I basically want this as the resulting SQL:

```
SELECT 
    "api2_testcaseresult"."result",
    SUM("api2_testcaseresult"."duration") AS "duration",
    COUNT("api2_testcaseresult"."result") AS "result_count"
FROM "api2_testcaseresult"
WHERE "api2_testcaseresult"."run_result_id" = 3
GROUP BY "api2_testcaseresult"."result";
```

Note how 'duration' is not part of the 'group by' clause.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply append a second `annotate()`:

```
qs = (TestCaseResult.objects
    .filter(run_result=run_result)
    .values('result')
    .annotate(result_count=Count('result'))
    .annotate(result_duration=Sum('duration'))
    )
```

This should give you exactly the desired SQL query.